# Functionality of as-pattern, non overlapping pattern through 'as pattern'

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, overlapping-matches, as-pattern

I am new to functional programming and haskell in particular and have two questions abound as-pattern and the reduction of overlappings through using it.
Giving the following code example:

```
last1 :: [a]          ->  a
last1    [x]          =   x
last1    (x:xs)       =   last xs

last2 :: [a]          ->  a
last2    [y]          =   y
last2    (y:ys@(_:_)) =   last ys
```

`last1` should be non overlapping in comparison to `last2`.
Lets take a look at the specific String `f:[]`. It would match to `[x]` and `(x:xs)` in `last1`.

In `last2`it would match to `[y]`. But not to `(y:ys@(_:_))`, because `ys` has to match `(_:_)` and just fulfills the first any pattern with `[]`.

Are my assumptions correct?

Now take a look at the specific String `f:o:o:[]`. Now the pattern `(y:ys@(_:_))` matches. In this case I am curious how the binding works. What is `ys` after the first call? I assume it is `o:o:[]`.

Comment: Why not `x1:x2:_`? I don't see any reason to use "as" pattern here.

Comment: It is an example from my professor to descripe as-pattern and bindings. But it is more a mention than an explaination.

Comment: @dredozubov: How would you know what to recurse on in your example?

Comment: @Guvante my point is: there is no need to alias subexpressions

Comment: @dredozubov: Your example drops the rest of the list and thus cannot work. `x1:x2:xs` could work but `x1:x2:_` cannot recurse on the remainder of the list making getting the last item impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursion is going to `last` in both cases, not `last1`/`last2`.

> `last1` should be non overlapping in comparison to `last2`.
>   Lets take a look at the specific String `f:[]`. It would match to `[x]` and `(x:xs)` in `last1`.

It could match `(x:xs)` but it won't as pattern matching will only match the first success. Overlaps are not ambiguous in this regard (the first definition is always taken).

> In `last2`it would match to `[y]`. But not to `(y:ys@(_:_))`, because `ys` has to match `(_:_)` and just fulfills the first any pattern with `[]`.

Your phrasing is a bit odd but you are correct that `f:[]` cannot match to `(y:ys@(_:_))` as the latter is basically matching on `_:_:_` which isn't a match.

> Now take a look at the specific String `f:o:o:[]`. Now the pattern `(y:ys@(_:_))` matches. In this case I am curious how the binding works. What is `ys` after the first call? I assume it is `o:o:[]`.

`ys` does equal `o:o:[]` (or `"oo"` or `[o,o]`).

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are the same in Haskell, as the first matching equation is used. Your second function is a bit more explicit about it, but the first is more idiomatic.